# Copy very large SharePoint list from one Site to another (on the same tenant)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a very large SharePoint list of about 2,000,000 items. We are working on optimizing this and breaking it up. However, we need to first copy this large 2m list to another SharePoint site that we can use for testing/proof of concepts.

I know PowerAutomate can do 100k rows...but that's it. Is there a PowerShell cmdlet or other script/api/tool that can help me do this?

We are even open to copying the ENTIRE site to the test site...if that is an option.